# how to add watermark image in qweb report in all pdf pages odoo 13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

this code is displaying watermark on first page only :
Note that i'm using odoo 13.

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="inside">
            <!--class="o-watermark"-->
               <div   style="opacity:0.25;top:55%;position: absolute;text-align:center;width:95%;">
               <img src="/profile_atp_keiner/static/src/img/watermarks.png"/>
            </div>
        </xpath>
```

Comment: As far as I know Odoo renders the content over several pages and does not recreate the HTML structure for each page. Accordingly there is only one div element with the class "page". The easiest way I can think of to display something on every page is to display these elements in the header or footer (external layout). If you change your xpath accordingly, your code should probably work.

Comment: yes this is what i have tried in the first time but as odoo 13 doesnot handel it header take all the page without showing the page class so i have tried this solution that can display my watermark but only on the first page :/ so i'm asking if anyone has done it in odoo 13 because using header is woorking in odoo 10 - 11

Comment: Maybe we are talking past each other or I just don't understand what you want, but if I put your codeblock (except the opacity property) in Odoo 13 in the header of the selected external layout the image will be displayed on every page.

Comment: it will be displayed on every page but not in background of the pdf report it will be ON the page class that contain information this is the problem of this code it's working in one page because i have put it inside the page class .